# Passing data from form to controller in php

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I used following code in view.php file. How to pass name and email to the controller.php file.

```
    <?php $input = '1' ?>

    <div>
        <form action="<?php echo $input; ?>" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Any help can be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but this might be what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo "Name: " . $name . "<br />";
echo "Email: " . $email;

?>

    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```